# How do I get an APIUsername, APIPassword for the Paypal live?

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox

i have implemented the PayPal Express CheckOut Payment Method.

For SandBox Mode i have used :

$config['Sandbox'] = TRUE;

$config['APIVersion'] = '85.0';

$config['APIUsername'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'sd_1343200577_biz_api1.cc.net' : 'smsthreads@smsthreads.com';

$config['APIPassword'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? '******' : 'PRODUCTION_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE';

$config['APISignature'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'AT4ajMclTj-jvhyMzN1.QC92FSBxAvBRxmuR5zhQBpe.GL5IRm8gyHxd' : 'PRODUCTION_SIGNATURE_GOES_HERE';

$config['DeviceID'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? '' : 'PRODUCTION_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE';

$config['ApplicationID'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'APP-80W284485P519543T' : 
'PRODUCTION_APP_ID_GOES_HERE';

$config['DeveloperEmailAccount'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? 'abc@anc.net' : 'PRODUCTION_DEV_EMAIL_GOES_HERE';

Its Time to go live now

So how to get all this For Live Payment

APIUsername
APIPassword
APISignature
DeviceID
ApplicationID
DeveloperEmailAccount

Thanks in Advance

-John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Go here and login](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run).  It will return your live credentials for you.

Comment: wow!!! Its works for me... But this only gave me APIUserName, API Password and APISignature. What about ApplicationID?? where to get this too?

Comment: Application ID is only used with Adaptive Payments so you don't need that for Express Checkout.  If you do something with Adaptive Payments, though, you get your live App ID by submitting the app for approval through your PayPal developer account.

Comment: Just curious why it's need developer's email id?

Comment: It's just something that's required in the headers that you send to PayPal.  I think it's because they match it up to ensure the App ID you're using belongs to that same developer account.